# Line chart - changing border width removes space

Tags: c#, graphics

I am creating a line chart and I want to increase the height or thickness of the line  without changing the length of the line.

Before increasing the width property, it looks like this:

[image: Chart before altering the width]

After increasing the width property, it looks like this:

[image: Chart after altering the width property]

I want to increase just the `height`, but there is no such property for this, so I tried altering the `width` property. Unfortunately, this increases both the `length` and `width`. Is there anyway to alter only the `height`? If I increase the `width`, as you can see, the space between the lines disappears.

Comment: Can you show us what you would like it to look like?

Comment: Have you tried the `BorderWidth` property?

Comment: You will probably have to resort to direct pixel manipulation at some point, or drawing multiple (vertical) 1px-wide lines instead of long horizontal ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by removing the start and end caps for the line. When I increased the border width, it also increased the start and end cap widths, which caused the strange behavior. The comments in the code below resolved it:

```
void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    float[] dashValues = { 8, 5, 2, 4 };
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
    blackPen.DashPattern = dashValues;
    blackPen.Width = 3;
    //blackPen.StartCap=LineCap.Round
    blackPen.StartCap =LineCap.Flat;
    //blackPen.StartCap=LineCap.Round
    blackPen.EndCap = LineCap.Flat;
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, new Point(85, 95), new Point(405, 95));
}
```